# Command to clear log files in symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I was wondering if there is a command to clear the log files in Symfony 2 ?
While there is the `php app/console cache:clear` to clear the cache, I don't know any command to clear the log files (logs/dev.log and logs/prod.log).
I have always cleared these logs manually.
Thank you

Comment: What's your OS? Base on your OS as @lxg says you can write a proper shell script

Answer (score 12):

There's no explicit command in Symfony. But using a shell one-liner is nothing to be ashamed of:

```
# straightforward …
echo -n '' > app/logs/dev.log

# … or l33t
> app/logs/dev.log # works at least in bash, haven't tried others
```

Answer (score 8):

For development environment you could use

```
cat /dev/null > app/logs/dev.log
```

and for production env

```
cat /dev/null > app/logs/prod.log
```

`/dev/null` into unix systems is a *virtual device* (**virual file** actually, because everything is a file in unix) that discard every data written on it. It is also called bit bucket :)

Moreover, why don't you think about take advantage of [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)? 
That way you could easily separate your logs (day-week-month and so on) and never lost "important" data. Last but not least, you don't have to clear logs file manually

Comment: Thnk you for response. I didn't know about logrotate, I will have a look at it

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple Symfony Command for clearing the logs, written for Symfony > 2.8. The difference/benefit over clearing the whole log-dir is that it only deletes the log for the specified environment and not custom log files that might have been added -  in my case a requirement.

ConsoleCommand:

```
namespace Std\AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ClearLogsCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var SymfonyStyle
     */
    private $io;
    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $fs;
    private $logsDir;
    private $env;

    /**
     * ClearLogsCommand constructor.
     *
     * @param null|string $logsDir
     * @param             $env
     */
    public function __construct($logsDir, $env)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->logsDir = $logsDir;
        $this->env = $env;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('std:logs:clear')
            ->setDescription('Deletes all logfiles');
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface  $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $this->fs = new Filesystem();

        $log = $this->logsDir . '/' . $this->env . '.log';
        $this->io->comment(sprintf('Clearing the logs for the <info>%s</info> environment', $this->env));
        $this->fs->remove($log);
        if (!$this->fs->exists($log)) {
            $this->io->success(sprintf('Logs for the "%s" environment was successfully cleared.', $this->env));
        } else {
            $this->io->error(sprintf('Logs for the "%s" environment could not be cleared.', $this->env));
        }
    }
}
```

The service config would be:

```
services:
    std.command.clear_logs_command:
        class: Std\AppBundle\Command\ClearLogsCommand
        arguments: ['%kernel.logs_dir%', '%kernel.environment%']
        tags:
           -  { name: console.command }
```

To execute run:

```
app/console std:logs:clear --env=prod
```

Or as a gist:
[https://gist.github.com/HKandulla/5de5a4074a5296b9465b4825431dfff3#file-clearlogscommand-php][1]

Comment: Thanks for this. I will just add to your answer. For me, this services configuration worked on Symfony 4.2.9:

    App\Command\ClearLogsCommand:
        arguments:
            $logsDir: '%kernel.logs_dir%'
            $env: '%kernel.environment%'

Comment: You can also let autowiring do the work for you. All you have to do is add the parameters in a `bind` section under `_defaults` like this: `$env: "%kernel.environment%" $logsDir: "%kernel.logs_dir%"`.
Also, unlike a minimal bash script, using a SF command prevents permission issues and hard coded parameters.