# Clearing logs in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, logging

Is it possible to clear the logs in Symfony? I mean, is there any command that could clear its logs using windows? I believe that there is also a command that would clear the logs since there is this command in windows that could clear the cache:

`php app\console cache:clear`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know `cache:clear` doesn't touch your logs. If you wanted to to clear them you could try deleting them or empty the file using something along the lines of `nul > YOUR_FILE.ext`. I'm only getting my ideas from StackOverflow and I know what sort of chaos they/we endorse so I could be wrong.

Comment: Please see my answer to:
[Command to clear log files in symfony 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914149/command-to-clear-log-files-in-symfony-2/38873017#38873017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony2 Standard Edition, not found command or function for clear logs.
But, you can create custom [command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) for clear logs and another functions.
The command `cache:clear` clear only caches (`app/cache/{environment}` or `var/cache/{environment}`)

Answer (score 0):

The most useful command for that:

```
rd /s /q app\logs\prod app\logs\dev
```

Comment: `rd` is standard windows console command for deleting directories. And it is easy to remember as "Remove Directory"